# What's the word for "the item which is sold"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes a part or item being sold. The word should describe the individual items, not the product line, and should make no delineation between different products. It should just mean "an item which we sell, or is sold". Here's a simple example:

You work at a store that sells widgets. There are multiple product lines. You've got your standard widgets and your deluxe widgets. You have multiple stock of each product.

I want to say somethings like the following:

"Check that all the *items to be sold* are properly packaged"

"Each *item to be sold* must be tested before going on the shelf"

"Count how many deluxe *items to be sold* are in stock"

"Product" does not work as it describes the entire product line. "Part" is too vague, as it has too many other meanings, including the same as "product". "Stock" or "Stock item" does not work as it specifically means things which are in inventory.

Comment: How 'bout: *Check that all the widgets are properly packaged*? or *Check that all the items are properly packaged*?

Comment: Those would work if given proper context, but I'm looking for more specificity.

Comment: Insofar as you are only in the business of selling, the addition of "to be sold" is superfluous and each sentence should contain simply *item* or *items*.

Comment: [ware:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ware) 1.
Usually, wares.
articles of merchandise or manufacture; good...

[commodity:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commodity)an article of trade or commerce, especially a product as distinguished from a service.....


[asset:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asset) 
a single item of ownership having exchange value.

Comment: @KWinker Most businesses who sell also buy and keep stock of things which they do not sell. Think about office supplies, toilet paper...

Comment: I think *merchandise* would work.

Comment: I'd answer with *unit*, but I'm not sure from your question what sort of word you are really looking for.

Comment: I would actually say "items for sale" rather than "items to be sold".  Or goods, wares, merchandise, etc. as already suggested. The fact that you buy & stock items for internal use seems irrelevant - presumably the staff have some intelligence to understand what you're talking about?

Comment: In business school, we referred to a single item of inventory as a *unit* (e.g., "Check that all *units* are properly packaged";  "Each *unit* must be tested before going on the shelf";  and, "Count how many *units* are in stock.")

Comment: "Ware", "merchandise", and "unit" are the closest to what I'm going for. I think I'll use "unit".

Comment: _Product_ if it's mass, _products_ if they're count. Compounds are fine: _product items, product units,_ etc.

Comment: A *commodity* is a product that is (produced) for sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Product** is certainly preferable to **item being sold**, but have to be a little careful how we use it. This seems like a good working definition of the word:

> **product** a set of identical items produced for sale, e.g. "the new product will double our profits"
>
> **products** multiple of such sets, e.g. "the two new products will quadruple our profits"

You seem to be asking, how do you refer to a single element of such a set?

We observe product is a *mass noun* which refers to a set of things. **Bars of soap** and **liters of water** use units to identify a discrete part of the mass nouns **soap** and **water**. Similarly, **unit of product** could be used to identify a single item to be sold, although it sounds overly formal and almost academic.

> "Check that all the **units of product** are properly packaged."
>
> "Each **unit of product** must be tested before going on the shelf."
>
> "Count how many deluxe **units of product** are in stock."

Another option is to use *notional agreement*, a grammatical convention that allows a group noun to be used with a plural verb when the individuality of its parts is important. This type of construct sounds strange to me, but it is purportedly [not as rare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis) in British English.

> "Check that all the **product** are properly packaged."
>
> "Count how many deluxe **product** are in stock."

Going by ear, the second example ("Each of the product must be tested") is almost certainly wrong, although a real plural noun would work ("Each of the widgets must be tested"). Either notionally plural nouns are more limited than syntactically plural nouns, or my American ears are balking at something technically acceptable.

Although I hope we all enjoyed this brief look into mass nouns, I suggest you use **item** or **unit** in those sentences, or, if applicable, identify the thing being packaged, shelved, or stocked more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with **ware**.

> - articles of merchandise or manufacture; goods:
> - any intangible items, as services or products of artistic or intellectual creativity, that are salable

(dictionary.com)

"Check that all the wares are properly packaged"

Of course, the definition of "ware" also suggests **goods**.

"Each good must be tested before going on the shelf"

"Count how many deluxe goods are in stock"

Comment: Shouldn't that be "wares"?

Comment: Hi EightyEighty, can you add a source link for the definition you included?  Attribution is very important here on ELU.  :-)

Comment: Whoops! Attribution added. And yes, "ware" can be singular.